# Command line not recognizing 'djstripe_sync_plans_from_stripe' or 'djstripe_sync_plans'

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Has anyone else encountered / solved this issue? We've found no insight into this from the web. But as far as we can tell, I have to run at least one of these commands to sync our Stripe account with our Django database models.

The CLI command that's worked for all our other teammates has been:

`python3 manage.py djstripe_sync_plans_from_stripe`

The expectation, as I understand, is that this command should sync Django models from relevant data on the Stripe account, however my terminal doesn't recognize this command. This is the first time the team has experienced this while onboarding a new collaborator. One command that is recognized is:

`python3 manage.py djstripe_sync_models`

This command produces a number of funky errors which may or may not be related to the issue at hand, but it does run. This illustrates that some of these "djstripe" commands are recognized, just not the one that we need. Bottom line, we need to find a fix or a workaround.